Why does "send-mailmessage" work in Powershell Console and VS Code but not in Azure PowerShell Runbook?
I am trying to send an email from PowerShell runbook.
The script I use is:
Send-mailmessage -from "noreply@company.com" -to "me@company.com" -subject "test" -smtpserver "smtp_server"

It fails with an error message:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.


Possibly the smtp server / a firewall is blocking the connection from Azure.

Adding to my last comment, you might probably solve this issue using a hybrid worker instead

@SantiagoSquarzon I am using hybrid worker even though it fails. Any settings need to be done in hybrid worker?. fyi I am using windows as hybrid worker

If you are targeting an Azure SMTP server or relay service, maybe try specifying -Port 587.  -UseSSL may also be needed.

Have you tried pinging smtp mail server before sending an email message with this command. ping smtp.gmail.com @Mukesh
